# Removing a platform from Visual Studio solution programatically?

Tags: templates, wizard

I am working on a template (wizard) based on a .js file that configures project settings in Visual Studio 2012. The template is for 64 bit DLLs.

I am currently setting `x64` in the JavaScript file using:

```
Proj.ConfigurationManager.AddPlatform("x64", "Win32", true);
```

This does propagate the `x64` option in the solution file, however, I was wondering if I could remove the `Win32` option or have it as second in the drop down (first one being `x64`).

Comment: Im also looking for a solution to this. Couldn't find yet. Could you?